# Smooth paths on affine varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

I have the following question which is in some way related to an application of Randell Isotopy Theorem to complex hyperplane arrangements.

Let $h,k\geq1$ be integer numbers and let $F_{1},\ldots,F_{h}$ be elements of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}\left[t_{1},\ldots,t_{k}\right].$ Now, consider the space $$X=\lbrace P\in\mathbb{C}^{k}\mid F_{j}(P)=0\text{ for }1\leq j\leq h\rbrace$$
where $F_{j}(P)$ simply denotes the evaluation of the polynomials $F_{j}$ at the point $P.$

Let us assume $X$ is endowed with the $\textit{classical}$ topology.
In general $X$ is not a topological manifold. However, I have the following question regarding the path connectivity of the connected components of $X.$
In fact, $X$ a locally path connected space, so that its connected components coincide with its path connected components. To be more precise, my question regards the smoothness of paths connecting points in $X.$

$\textbf{Definition:}$ A path $\gamma:\left(a,b\right)\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}^{k}$ is called $\textit{smooth}$ 
                     if every derivative of any order are continuous.

$\textbf{Remark:}$
 Pay attention that this definition of smoothness is different from the one of $\textit{regularity}$ of a parametrized curve. I am NOT asking the tangent vector $\gamma'(t)$ is not vanishing.

$\textbf{QUESTION:}$ Let $P,Q\in X$ be two points of $X$ which are in the same connected component. Then, there exists $\epsilon>0$ and a smooth path 
$\gamma:\left(-\epsilon,1+\epsilon\right)\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}^{k}$ with 
$\gamma(t)\in X$ for any $t\in\left(-\epsilon,1+\epsilon\right)$ and such that
$\gamma(0)=P$ and $\gamma(1)=Q.$

Answer (score 5):

This is true. It is easy to find a piecewise smooth path by following the smooth strata. Then reparameterize the path so that it becomes smooth by stopping of infinite order at each point where it it is not smooth (use pieces $t\mapsto e^{-1/t^2}$).

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion! I was pretty sure that a smart use of the exponential map solve my problem. However, your answer confirm my first impressions. With this result in mind, I am now able to build a smooth lattice isotopy in my moduli space of arrangements. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

**Edit.** Peter Michor showed that the answer to the question is **yes**. By contrast, the following example shows that it is in general **no** when one replaces *smooth path* with *regular path* (I at first assumed that *smooth* and *regular* were used here as synonims, as sometimes happens in the literature, see the discussion in the comments below).

Take the connected affine space $X:=\{z_1z_2=0 \} \subset \mathbb{C}^2$. Under the identification $\mathbb{C}^2 = \mathbb{R}^4$ given by $$(x_1+x_2i, \, x_3 + x_4 i) \mapsto (x_1, \, x_2, \, x_3, \, x_4),$$ the underlying real space of $X$ is the connected union of two planes $$\Pi_1 \cup \Pi_2,$$ 
where $\Pi_1=\{x_1=x_2=0\}, \quad \Pi_2 =\{x_3 = x_4 =0\}$.

Let us take two points $p_1 \in \Pi_1$ and $p_2 \in \Pi_2$. Then any continuous path $\gamma(t)$ such that $\gamma(0)=p_1$ and $\gamma(1)= p_2$ must contain the origin $\mathbf{0}=(0, \, 0, \, 0, \, 0)=\Pi_1 \cap \Pi_2$, so there exists $t_0 \in (0, \, 1)$ such that $\gamma(t_0)=\mathbf{0}$.

Now, the path $\gamma(t)$ is clearly *not* regular at $t_0$. In fact, we have $$\lim_{t \to t_0^-} \gamma'(t) \in \Pi_1, \quad \lim_{t \to t_0^+} \gamma'(t) \in \Pi_2,$$

so if $\gamma(t)$ is smooth at $t_0$ it follows $\gamma'(t_0)=\mathbf{0}.$

Comment: Are you sure that there is no way to find a path such that $\operatorname{lim}_{t\rightarrow t_{0}^{-}}\gamma'(t)=\operatorname{lim}_{t\rightarrow t_{0}^{+}}\gamma'(t)=0$?

Comment: In this case $\gamma'(t_0)=0$ and so $\gamma(t)$ is not regular at $t_0$.

Comment: But I am not looking at regular paths, just smooth paths.

Comment: Sorry, what is your definition of *smooth*? For me (and for the literature) is equivalent to $C^{\infty}$ parametrization, or at least $C^1$ parametrization. This means in particular that $\gamma'$ must be continuous and $\gamma'(t) \neq 0$ for all $t \in (0, \, 1)$. The tangent vector must be *nonzero* at every point!

Comment: I am sorry. I use the word $\textit{regular}$ for your $\textit{smooth}.$ To me, and as far I know before, $\textit{smooth}$ just means that all derivatives of any order are continuous.

Comment: For a parametrized curve this is a strange definition, since it is really *not* enough to guarantee the smoothness of the support (that is what one usually desires). For instance, the cuspidal curve $(t^2, t^3)$ is smooth with your definition, but the support is clearly singular at $(0, 0)$. Are you sure this is what you are looking for?

Comment: I know what you mean and I already had your conterexamples in mind, both the one in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ and the cuspidal curve. However, in order to apply the Randell Isotopy Theorem to a certain moduli space of hyperplane arrangement, I just need the condition I specified you.

Comment: Now everything fits. Thank you again to everyone!